# Ruby on Rails 7 Argument Error (given 0, expected 1) When User Selects Timeframe to Update Chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arguments, parameter-passing, chartkick, stimulusjs

hoping you can help, even ChatGPT4 can't fix this problem.

I have a Ruby on Rails 7 app that I am trying to query an API to pull the sales of items based on the user selected timeframe e.g., 7 days, 30 days, and 90 days.

I am getting an argument error `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))` but it looks like the parameters are being passed in this line before it: `Parameters: {"timeframe"=>"90_days", "static_page"=>{"timeframe"=>"90_days"}}` because I set the default to 30 days so I know 90 days is being selected by the user

I am attempting to use Stimulus and the Chartkick Gem to make this work.
Any help at all is very appreciated!

Here is my latest_sales_controller.js file:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["latestSalesChart"]

  updateChart(event) {
    const timeframe = event.target.value;
    console.log("Timeframe dara:", timeframe);  // log the timeframe to the console
    const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

    const body = JSON.stringify({ timeframe });
    console.log("Body Data", body);

    fetch('/home/last_sales_chart', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
      },
      body
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Response Data');  // log the response data to the console
      console.log(data);  // log the response data to the console
      const chartData = data.chart_data;
      console.log("Chart Data", chartData)
      const chart = Chartkick.charts[this.latestSalesChartTarget.id];
      chart.updateData(chartData);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

Here is my static_pages_controller.rb file:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    require 'httparty'
    require 'groupdate'

    puts "last sales: #{last_sales_chart}"


   @chart_data = last_sales_chart


    puts "chart data #{@chart_data.inspect}"

  end

  def about
  end

  def last_sales_chart
    timeframe = params[:timeframe]
    timewindow = get_timewindow(timeframe)
    chart_data = generate_chart_data(timewindow)

    return chart_data
  end

  private

  def get_timewindow(timeframe)
    current_day = DateTime.now
    case timeframe
    when "7_days"
      (current_day - 7).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    when "30_days"
      (current_day - 30).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    when "90_days"
      (current_day - 90).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    else
      (current_day - 30).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    end
  end

  def generate_chart_data(timewindow)
    puts "Timewindow data #{timewindow}"
    query = {
      query: "query LastSalePrice {
        tokens(where: {fa2_address: {_eq: \"KT1LHHLso8zQWQWg1HUukajdxxbkGfNoHjh6\"},
        events: {timestamp: {}}, last_sale_at: {_gte: \"#{timewindow}\"}},
        order_by: {last_sale_at: desc_nulls_last, last_sales_price: asc}) {
          fa2_address
          last_sale_at
          last_sales_price
          token_id
          name
        }
      }"
    }

    response = HTTParty.post('https://api.teztok.com/v1/graphql',
                             body: query.to_json,
                             headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })

    response_body = JSON.parse(response.body)

    data = response_body["data"]["tokens"].map do |token|
      { timestamp: token["last_sale_at"], token_id: token["token_id"],
        last_sales_price: sprintf('%.6f', token["last_sales_price"]/1000000.0) }
    end

    chart_data = []
    data.each do |d|
      chart_data << [d[:timestamp], d[:last_sales_price]]
    end

    return chart_data

  end

end
```

Here is my view partial _last_sales_chart.html.erb file:

```
<div class="outside"
  data-controller="latest-sales"
  data-latest-sales-chart-target="latestSalesChart">

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'timeframe', 'Select Timeframe', class: 'form-label' %>
    <%= select_tag :timeframe, options_for_select([['Last 7 Days', '7_days'], ['Last 30 Days', '30_days'], ['Last 90 Days', '90_days']]), data: { action: "change->latest-sales#updateChart" } %>
  </div>

  <div id="latest-sales">
    <h3><a href="https://objkt.com/collection/tezzardz"
           target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" id="nft-name">Tezzardz</a> Sales Over the Last Month</h3>
      <div id="chart">
        <%= line_chart @chart_data, suffix: "ꜩ", id: "latestSalesChart", ytitle: "Last Sales Price ꜩ", points: false %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  draw :madmin
  root "static_pages#home"

  post "/home/last_sales_chart", to: "static_pages#home#last_sales_chart"

  get "/about",  to: "static_pages#about"

end
```

Here is my gem file:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.2"

gem "rails",                    "7.0.3"
gem "faker",                    "2.21.0"
gem "sassc-rails",              "2.1.2"
gem "sprockets-rails",          "3.4.2"
gem "importmap-rails",          "1.1.0"
gem "turbo-rails",              "1.1.1"
gem "stimulus-rails",           "1.0.4"
gem "jbuilder",                 "2.11.5"
gem "puma",                     "5.6.4"
gem "devise"
gem "bootsnap",                 "1.12.0", require: false
gem "madmin",                   "~> 1.2"
gem 'httparty'
gem 'chartkick'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'bootstrap',                "~> 5.2.2"
gem "will_paginate-bootstrap-style"

# Bundle and transpile JavaScript [https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails]
gem "jsbundling-rails"

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"
  gem "debug",   "1.5.0", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console", "4.2.0"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara",                 "3.37.1"
  gem "selenium-webdriver",       "4.2.0"
  gem "webdrivers",               "5.0.0"
  gem "rails-controller-testing", "1.0.5"
  gem "minitest",                 "5.15.0"
  gem "minitest-reporters",       "1.5.0"
  gem "guard",                    "2.18.0"
  gem "guard-minitest",           "2.4.6"
end

group :production do
  gem "pg", "1.3.5"
end
```

And here is the error in the Rails server that I'm getting:

```
Processing by StaticPagesController#update_chart_data as */*
  Parameters: {"timeframe"=>"30_days", "static_page"=>{"timeframe"=>"30_days"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 802)


  
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
  
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:17:in `update_chart_data'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at using `byebug` or `ruby-debug` gems? Can you step through and find the line with the error?

Comment: Are you sure it cannot solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you @Jad I used byebug to really help me understand the problem and learned a lot about the variables I was trying to access. Ultimately helped me get to my final solution using Turbo Frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `update_chart_data` is an action in the controller, I don't think it should receive arguments. The declaration of it should be like `def update_chart_data` You have to take a `timeframe` directly from `params`

Comment: You're right, doing that I was able to get the params to pass correctly but now I get a `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` in my console logs. Based on other debugging I believe there is something wrong in my js controller when i call `fetch`. Still trying to figure out what it is but I believe it may be the incorrect params is being passed.

Comment: Came back and marking this answer as correct. The answer ultimately answered my original question about passing arguments. The final solution required me to rework my code and use turbo frames.